# runtime analysis of bubble sort similar algorithm

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, bubble-sort, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having a lot of trouble finding the running time of the following algorithm. I would thank very much if someone could help me to solve it explicitly line per line with the corresponding cost and amount of times it is executed. My biggest problem is calculating the amount of times the while-loop is executed.

```
Algo: (A,n)
tmp = 0;
do
  ready = 0;
  for i = n-1 to 1 do
    if A[i-1]>A[i] then
       temp=A[i-1];
       A[i-1] = A[i];
       A[i] = tmp;  
       ready = 1;

  for i = 1 to n-1 do
    if A[i-1]>A[i] then
       temp=A[i-1];
       A[i-1] = A[i];
       A[i] = tmp;  
       ready = 1;

while ready = 1;
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The worst case for bubble sort is O(n^2).

The problem with bubble sort is that for i to n times you iterate the whole array.

The amount of times and the rest sounds like home to me.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I know the bubble sort is O(n^2) and that this algorithm is iterating over the whole array two times each time it enters in the while-loop. My problem is finding out how many times it actually enters in the while-loop.